# {field:payment_method} doesn't output anything

Tags: expresso-store, sagepay

I'm struggling to get a payment method to be output in the checkout tag.

I'm using this code:

```
<div class="field">
    {field:payment_method}
    {error:payment_method}
</div>
```

I just get an empty select element:

[image: empty select element]

I've got the "server" option enabled in the backend:

[image: SagePay_Server option enabled]

Though there doesn't seem to be any extra option that I have to pass, shouldn't there be a username/password normally?

[image: SagePay_Server settings]

Comment: Has this been resolved? I have the same issue.

Comment: Just added an answer to this thread!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I hard coded the payment methods as radio inputs with the values as the payment method name. It's still worth keeping the error:payment_method tag as I think it gives gateway errors. I don't know what expression store do now, it was constantly breaking and changing all the time when I developed this site.